# Дополнительный HDD не определяется в BIOS

Tags: ос, bios, hdd, ssd

Поставил SSD на место HDD, а его через переходник поставил вместо привода для дисков. На нем установлена винда и убунту. Однако когда решил загрузиться с него, в биосе его почему то не оказалось. При этом, если загрузиться с основного диска и ОС, все отлично работает.  В настройках ничего не нашел что хоть как то указывало бы на решение проблемы. В гугле тоже ничего внятного не встретил. На SSD установлена убунту. Как загрузиться с диска установленного вместо привода?